# How to sort multiple dicts in list with key (google babyname exercise_modified)

Tags: python

This is a modified list I created from google babyname exercise.

```
[
[{'year': 1998}, {'rank': 1, 'boy': 'pic', 'girl': 'Emy'}, {'rank': 2, 
'boy': 'badf', 'girl': 'Hdf'}, ...{'rank': 1000, 'boy': 'Jal', 'girl': 
'Sky'}],
[{'year': 1999}, {'rank': 1, 'boy': 'xic', 'girl': 'Ely'}, {'rank': 2, 
'boy': 'aacb', 'girl': 'Hah'}, ...{'rank': 1000, 'boy': 'Jal', 'girl': 
'Sky'}],
[{'year': 1958}, {'rank': 1, 'boy': 'Mic', 'girl': 'Emy'}, {'rank': 2, 
'boy': 'caob', 'girl': 'Han'}, ...{'rank': 1000, 'boy': 'Jal', 'girl': 
'Sky'}],
 ....
]
```

How to sort this list with different keys? such as year, rank....

Comment: This data is badly structured.

Comment: The approach for sorting by year is going to be a bit different from the approach for sorting by rank, or boy, etc. What have you tried? I'll second what COLDSPEED said --- this data could be structured much better.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should include details of what you have tried so far and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks. Do you have any suggestion on the data structure?

Comment: @XiaoboLi change your data structure to `Dataframe`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ agree ~

Comment: @Wen  Yes. Dataframe works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I convert the list dict to `pandas  DataFrame` which make `sort` become easier

```
LIST=[[{'year': 1998}, {'rank': 1, 'boy': 'pic', 'girl': 'Emy'}, {'rank': 2,
'boy': 'badf', 'girl': 'Hdf'},{'rank': 1000, 'boy': 'Jal', 'girl':
'Sky'}],
[{'year': 1999}, {'rank': 1, 'boy': 'xic', 'girl': 'Ely'}, {'rank': 2,
'boy': 'aacb', 'girl': 'Hah'},{'rank': 1000, 'boy': 'Jal', 'girl':
'Sky'}],
[{'year': 1958}, {'rank': 1, 'boy': 'Mic', 'girl': 'Emy'}, {'rank': 2,'boy': 'caob', 'girl': 'Han'},{'rank': 1000, 'boy': 'Jal', 'girl':'Sky'}]]
DFLIST=[]
for A in LIST:
    DFLIST.append(pd.DataFrame(A).ffill().dropna())
NEWDF=pd.concat(DFLIST,axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[540]: 
    boy girl    rank    year
0   pic  Emy     1.0  1998.0
1  badf  Hdf     2.0  1998.0
2   Jal  Sky  1000.0  1998.0
3   xic  Ely     1.0  1999.0
4  aacb  Hah     2.0  1999.0
5   Jal  Sky  1000.0  1999.0
6   Mic  Emy     1.0  1958.0
7  caob  Han     2.0  1958.0
8   Jal  Sky  1000.0  1958.0
```

For Example : sort by rank

```
NEWDF.sort_values(['year','rank'],ascending=[True,False])


Out[542]: 
    boy girl    rank    year
8   Jal  Sky  1000.0  1958.0
7  caob  Han     2.0  1958.0
6   Mic  Emy     1.0  1958.0
2   Jal  Sky  1000.0  1998.0
1  badf  Hdf     2.0  1998.0
0   pic  Emy     1.0  1998.0
5   Jal  Sky  1000.0  1999.0
4  aacb  Hah     2.0  1999.0
3   xic  Ely     1.0  1999.0
```

Comment: Brilliant! Nice answer.

Comment: @Wen Thanks a lot.